# Blender 2.8x Save Add-on Class Instance To Scene

Tags: python, add-on

In Blender 2.7x in the **init**.py file a generic class was instantiated for the purpose of holding data:

```
class HoldData(): 
    dat = None       

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)
    bpy.types.Scene.my_data = HoldData()

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_module(__name__)
    del bpy.types.Scene.my_data
```

In a subsequent file an outside python class is instantiated within the generic class, in this case a Pandas Dataframe:

```
import bpy
import pandas as pd

class OP_DoWork(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "op.dowork"
    bl_label  = "Doing Work"

def execute(self, context):
    return{'FINISHED'}

def invoke(self, context, event):
    dat = bpy.context.scene.my_data
    dat.bh = pd.DataFrame()
```

Finally, the object (the Pandas Dataframe) is accessible to other classes within Blender:

```
class OP_DataCheck(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "op.datacheck"
    bl_label = "Check Data"

    def __init__(self):
        self.dat = None

    def execute(self, context): 
        dat = bpy.context.scene.my_data
        print(dat.bh.columns)
```

In 2.8x the registration of the original HoldData() class throws an error:

```
class HoldData(bpy.types.Anytype):
AttributeError: 'RNA_Types' object has no attribute 'Anytype'
```

How can I save a class instance to the scene in Blender 2.8x?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what is often referred to as a monkey patch.  Data will not be saved to blend file.

To monkey patch onto a scene type could simply

```
import bpy

class HoldData: 
    dat = None       

def register():
    bpy.types.Scene.my_data = HoldData()

def unregister():
    del bpy.types.Scene.my_data
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Test in console

```
>>> C.scene.my_data.dat = "foo"
>>> C.scene.my_data.dat
'foo'
```

In as much as can do this, would favour simply

```
from foo import HoldData

my_data = HoldData()
```

and

```
from bah import my_data
```

To save some data to blender and use a third party for other recommend a `PropertyGroup` and `PointerProperty` set up.   Not all members of the defined property group need be annotated properties.

The other issue mentioned is a typo, the class is `bpy.types.AnyType` (*CamelCase ie capital T for type*)  Not sure where you're going with this either?

Comment: I should have been more clear. My last code snippet was a copy of the error displayed in the console when loading the add-on. Thanks for the answer- I've been beating my head on the wall for two days over this!